# Why eigenvector points to principal stress plane?

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, stress-strain, eigenvalue

I can represent a [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) by a matrix. Suppose we are talking about a 2nd order [tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor), and the matrix is therefore 3x3. If I find one eigenvector of that matrix; that vector represents normal vector on a plane on which there is no shear stress (the stress state was described by the 2nd order tensor). My question is, how is this happening (looking for the proof) that eigenvector points to a plane without shear stress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3 eigenvectors of the stress tensor/matrix $T$, you can choose them as your new basis and it will be diagonal there - and no off-diagonal elements mean no shear stress, since the shear stress on the plane in the $ij$-direction ($i \neq j$) is given by $T_{ij}$, which, for $i \neq j$, will be zero in this basis.

Answer (score 1):

Eigen vector:It is a vector that undergo only scaling and no rotation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tOcSuRkIzs   (for graphical intuition)

Since principle stress acts on normal direction(extends normally)without shear due to rotation 
eigen vectors are principle stress.

Answer (score 0):

When you post-multiply a stress tensor (a 3x3 matrix in your case) by a column vector comprising of the direction cosines of the (outward) normal to a plane, you get the traction vector (i.e. a column vector giving you the force per unit area-of-the-said-plane).

If the (outward) normal to the plane were in a 'principal direction', then, by definition, the traction vector has to be parallel (or anti-parallel) to the said normal vector. This is an Eigen value problem.

The Eigen vector here is the normal vector. What's the Eigen value? The magnitude of the force per unit area-of-the-said-plane, and that's the principal stress.

You have 3 principal directions and 3 principal stresses. In other words, you have 3 linear-independent Eigen vectors and hence 3 Eigen values.